# How to make touches propagation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gesture

For example

I have a custom UIView Class, on the view I put a UIButton.

In the View Class

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touch view");
}
```

But when I touch the button, it intercepted view touch message. Is there a way to recieve touches when user touch view's subview?

I noticed when using UIGestureRecognizer bind to the superview, the event can recieved when user touched subview.

Answer (score 0):

There is no (Apple-allowed or stable) way to "pass" touches to another view. Instead, call a method in your other view from your touches method.